# Getting An exception of type 'AutoMapper.AutoMapperMappingException' occurred in AutoMapper.dll but was not handled in user code

Tags: c#, automapper

Here's my Model:

```
public class Testing: Model
    {
        public IEnumerable<Entry> Entries { get; set; }
    }

public class Entry
    {
        public string testa{ get; set; }
        public string testb{ get; set; }
        public string testc{ get; set; }
        public string testd{ get; set; }
        public string teste{ get; set; }
        public string testf{ get; set; }
        public string testg{ get; set; }
        public string testh{ get; set; }
    }
```

heres the mapper:

```
public TestingMapper()
        {
            Mapper.CreateMap<Testing, DisplayForm>()
                .ForMember(dest => dest.Entries, opt => opt.MapFrom(source => source.Entries));
        }
```

here's DisplayForm

```
public partial class DisplayForm
    {
        public DisplayForm()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        public IEnumerable<Entry> Entries
        {
            get
            {
                return null;
            }
            set
            {
                worklist1.DataBind(value);
            }
        }
    }
```

But I am getting the error : 'AutoMapper.AutoMapperMappingException' occurred in AutoMapper.dll but was not handled in user code

When trying to do the mapping.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What does `DisplayForm` look like?

Comment: @AnthonyChu I added it to the question.

Comment: That setup seems weird, how do you call the mapper? Do you really create a new form by mapping from the model?

Comment: So why not debug it or catch the exception and check what it has to say?